# How can i get the check variable in the NewQuestion button to change the form check variable

Tags: c#, class, return-value

How can i get the check variable in the NewQuestion button to change the form check
variable.

im looking at using the check value in another button after this button has changed it.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

int check = 0;

private void btnNewQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int check = 1;
}
```

Comment: ***Where*** you *declare* a variable determines its *scope*.  Suggested reading: [Scope of Variables in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your main goal, I'm thinking there may better ways to do what you are trying to do. That said, you can simply reference your form level variable as you need to, within the same form.

```
public Form1()
{        
    InitializeComponent();
}

int check = 0; // form level variable

private void btnNewQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // int check = 1; // don't do this; this will create another 'check' variable that is only scoped within the button event
    check = 1; // to set the form level check value, just reference the form level variable like so
}

private void btnSomeOtherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // then reference it in the other button where you need it
    if(check == 1)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh by putting int in front of check make it a new variable. Awesome thank you very much.